# Additional attributes not working

Tags: magento

I am trying to add the following 2 additional attributes through API. I am not getting any error, however it is not getting uploaded. It would be great if some one could give me a suggestion.

```
catalogProductAdditionalAttributesEntity AdAtrributeEntity = new catalogProductAdditionalAttributesEntity();

associativeEntity[] AdditionalAttributes = new associativeEntity[2];
associativeEntity AdditionalAttributeOne = new associativeEntity();
associativeEntity AdditionalAttributeTwo = new associativeEntity();

AdditionalAttributeOne.key = "color";
AdditionalAttributeOne.value = "green";
AdditionalAttributeTwo.key = "size";
AdditionalAttributeTwo.value = "xl";

AdditionalAttributes[0] = AdditionalAttributeOne;
AdditionalAttributes[1] = AdditionalAttributeTwo;

AdAtrributeEntity.single_data = AdditionalAttributes;
ProductEntity.additional_attributes = AdAtrributeEntity;

MyService.catalogProductUpdate(Mylogin, SKU, ProductEntity, null, null)
```

Comment: Did you every figure this out?

I added a print statement in the API and it seems that the elements in the sngle_data array have lost all values.

[single_data] => Array(
  [0] => Array(
    [0] => stdClass Object()
    [1] => stdClass Object()
  )
)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is older, but I found a solution.  'single_data' and 'multi_data' need to have an array inside it that has the arrays of attributes.

```
product_data = {
          'name' => self.get_attribute_value('name'),
          'description' => self.get_attribute_value('description'),
          'short_description' => self.get_attribute_value('short_description'),
          'weight' => self.get_attribute_value('weight'),
          'status' => self.get_attribute_value('status'),
          'categories' => compose_categories,
          'url_key' => self.get_attribute_value('url_key'),
          'price' => self.get_attribute_value('price'),
          'additional_attributes' => { 'single_data' => { items: compose_attribute_values }}
}
```

In the example, I named the additional array 'item', hoever, you can call it whatever you want.  I used 'item' because the API returns many values like that.  The additional attributes look something like this in PHP:

```
...
'additional_attributes' = array(
    'single_data' => array(
        'item' => array(
            [0] => array(
                'key' => 'some_attribute_code',
                'value' => 'some_attribute_value'
            )
            [1] => array(
                'key' => 'some_other_attribute_code',
                'value' => 'some_other_attribute_value'
            )
        )
    )
)
...
```

Answer (score 2):

This work for add `additional_attributes`:

```
'additional_attributes' => array(
    'single_data' => array(
        array(
            'key' =>'manufacturer',
            'value' => '10'
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Example for Java** ([Apache XML-RPC](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlrpc) client + [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)):

I have attribute `manufacturer` with option: `Adidas` (ID: 318)

Product entity:

```
...
@SerializedName("additional_attributes")
private Map<String,Map<String,String>> additionalAttributes;
...
// getters + setters
...
```

code:

```
...
Map<String,String> attribute = new HashMap<>();
attribute.put("manufacturer", "318");

Map<String,Map<String,String>> additionalAttributes = new HashMap<>();
additionalAttributes.put("single_data", attribute);

product.setAdditionalAttributes(additionalAttributes);
...
```

then do [product.update](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/soap/catalog/catalogProduct/catalog_product.update.html) api request

p.s: of course it's a little bit weird, but you can wrap that with some facade